# unable to install truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-test, truffle-deployment, truffle-compile

I'm trying to install truffle on node version 8.9.0 but it shows it has been installed and when I try to do anything on that, throws this error.

```
C:\Users\com\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.0\node_modules\truffle\build\282.bundled.js:64897
  } catch {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.__webpack_require__.f.require (C:\Users\com\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.0\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:611:28)
```

I'm stuck on this for a while so please help me asap.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different node version. You can install and use a new version by saying:

```
nvm install 12.20.2
nvm use 12.20.2
```

And then check if the correct version is being used with `nvm list`. You should see something like this:

```
  * 12.20.2 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    8.9.0
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You very much, you are my savior. I was struggling with it for so long......